# Use a Variable in update_post_meta as the $meta_key

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, variables, post-meta

looking at the example on wordpress.org

> update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );

I seem to be having a problem replacing $meta_key  with a variable.    here is my code

**Part 1**

Setting the $week

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Week">
<option value="week_1">1</option>
<option value="week_2">2</option>
<option value="week_3">3</option>
<option value="week_4">4</option>
<option value="week_5">5</option>
<option value="week_6">6</option>
<option value="week_7">7</option>
<option value="week_8">8</option>
</select>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Selected a Week" >Selected a Week</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$week = $_POST['Week'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected : ".$week." to be edited";  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>
```

If you echo $week all is ok.

**Part 2**

```
$current_post   =   $post->ID;
$title          =   get_the_title();
$s1             =   $title . "s1";

$week_s1        =   "_member_score_".$week._s1";
$post_information = array(
// Look at this //
'ID'            =>  $current_post,
'post_title'    =>  $title,
'post-type'     =>  'CTP-Name',
'post_status'   =>  'publish',
);
$pidac = wp_update_post($post_information);
if($pidac)
{
update_post_meta($pidac, $week_s1, $_POST[$s1]);
$term_ids = array( 2, 7 );
$taxonomy = 'Custom-Taxonomy';
wp_set_object_terms( $pidac, $term_ids, $taxonomy );
// Redirect
wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
}
```

If you echo $week_s1 all is ok

If you  replace the  the variable $week_s1 with  the typed out value "_member_score_week_1_s1"  the code works perfectly.Here is the example

```
update_post_meta($pidac, "_member_score_week_1_s1" , $_POST[$s1]);
```

Can someone please advise me on how I can use the ($week_s1 ) variable  in this code.

Comment: try $week_s1   =   '__member_score_'.$week.'_s1';

Comment: Hi Thank but no joy still not working

Comment: remove $_POST[$s1] and add just $s1 in update_post_meta($pidac,  $week_s1 , $s1);

Comment: Nope still no joy in get it working

Comment: what kind of value is `$_POST[get_the_title()."s1"]` ? there is no corresponding post key for that in your form... (ps `post-type` should be `post_type`)

Comment: Hi majick  '$_POST[get_the_title()."s1"]' is a value for the form '<input type="radio" name="<?php echo $s1 ;?>" value="1">'

Answer (score 0):

> There is an error in setting variable on this line:

```
$week_s1="_member_score_".$week._s1";
```

> this line should be

```
$week_s1 ="_member_score_".$week."_s1";
```

Comment: I fix the code but still no joy.